# React number input allows input like 012

Tags: reactjs

The following code example works well with `text` input type, but allows inputs like `012` or `0012` to be entered when using the `number` input type.

The `console.log` line always runs and shows the right value, and the App state is also correct when checked with React Developer Tools. It's only that the controlled input is not being "controlled" somehow.

Why is this happening, and what is the recommended way to use number inputs with React?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value
    const num = parseInt(value, 10)
    console.log(num)
    this.setState({ value: isNaN(num) ? '' : num })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="number" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `0012` is a number.

Comment: Not after parseInt(...., 10)

Comment: i think it's working as you are expecting, check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/08ecc97d/)

Comment: @MayankShukla then it's probably something with the React version. I'm using the latest create-react-app (React 15.6.1, Chrome 60 on OS X).

Comment: not sure about that, but i think it should not depent on react version.

Comment: Unless it's a bug in React, which it probably is.

Comment: haha @zsero - of course it is a react bug. why wouldn't it be, if it explains your issue :D

Comment: @DimitarChristoff it might actually be a bug, or a feature or something but it changed between 15.4 and 15.5. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you bind the model of the controlled input to a number in your state, which is not being changed between 012 and 12 - so it leaves it as is.

instead, you can do

```
render() {
  const value = this.state.value.toString()
  return <input type="number" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
}
```

the string will actually differ and it will re-render properly, stripping the leading 0. or, you could `setState({ value: String(num) })`

Comment: No the value should change between 01 -> 012. Same way as it should change between 0 -> 01. Yet it's not being updated.

Comment: It should change without `.toString()`, I believe.

Comment: I'll grant you that it is kind of strange but I'd argue binding non primitive values to inputs is not a good pattern anyway when the browser will serialise it and call the `toString` internally. If you change the type from `number` to `text`, it works as expected (but does not wash input). So, it may be a particular browser implementation around `input[type=number]`. Either way, this QnA site is about getting your code to work--which this does--not discussing what changes react devs need to make - that's for the GH issues.